# Unable to read data from txt file and keeps returning value 3221225477

Tags: c, file, pointers, struct

my teacher asked me to make a program that can read employee's ID, name and salary from txt file, but I'm currently struggling with writing code that can read the txt in order.

```
#include<stdio.h>

typedef struct em{
    char id[20];
    char name[256];
    float sal;
};

void read_file(em *a, int *i){
    FILE *p;
    *i=0;
    char x[20],y[20],z[20];
    bool isRead;
    p=fopen("D:/--LMS--/PRF192/Assignment_File/A.txt","r");
    if (p==NULL){
        printf("File not found...");
    } else {
    fscanf(p,"%s %s %s",x,y,z);
    while (fscanf(p,"%s %s %f",a[*i].id,a[*i].name,&a[*i].sal)!=EOF){
        *i++;   }       
    for (int t=1;t<=*i;t++){
        printf("%s\n%s\n%f\n",a[*i].id,a[*i].name,a[*i].sal);
    } 
} printf("Finished");
}

main(){
    em em[100];
    int amount=0;
    read_file(em,&amount);
}
```

It should output the file's data along with "Finished" as the final line.
File Data:

```
EmID    EmName      EmsalaryLevel
A001    EgsyPrub    3.4
A002    PattyEin    2.4
A003    TheodoreEly 4.5
```

Comment: It looks like you left the type name out of the `typedef`.  Add `em` to the end, just before the semicolon.

Comment: Did you mean `(*i)++`? Also, for your `read_file`, you may consider opening the file in the caller (`main()` here) and passing the `FILE *p` as a parameter. If you can't open the file in the caller, there is no reason to call the function to read it. Either way works. Passing `FILE *p` is just a bit more traditional.

Comment: `printf("File not found...");` --> `printf("File not found...\n"); return;`

Comment: 3221225477 is the same as 0xC0000005. Huhu, I bet you are on Windows ... ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While you have discovered the problem with `*i++` incrementing the pointer-address instead of the value at the address held by the pointer `(*i)++`, you would benefit from simplifying things by separating what you need to accomplish into distinct operations.

First, don't use *magic numbers* in your code (except where absolutely required like with the `scanf` *field-width* modifier) and don't use hardcoded strings or filenames. Instead, If you need a constant, `#define` one (or more), or use a global `enum` to do the same thing. That way you have one single place at the top of your code to change things if needed and you don't have to go picking through your declarations or loop limits to change things.

In your case, you can simply `#define` the needed constants, and you pass the filename to read as an argument to your program (that's what your *argument-count* and *argument-vector* are for, e.g. `int argc, char **argv`) For example:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define MAXID   20  /* don't use magic numbers in your code!         */
#define MAXEM  100  /* if you need a constant, #define one (or more) */
#define MAXNM  256
#define MAXC  1024
...
typedef struct {    /* struct for employee data */
    char id[MAXID];
    char name[MAXNM];
    float sal;
} employee;         /* (note: typedef name goes at end...) */
```

Now, looking at your data-file, you need to read two different types of lines of data. (1) a heading line with 3-categories that you call `x, y, z` (not descriptive, but we will run with it...), and (2) employee data consisting of and `id, name, sal` which you are currently storing in an array of struct (that's good!).

While the heading line could probably be a single line without being broken into `x, y, z`, you need some way to get that data back from your function. A simple way is to create a second `typedef` for a `struct` to hold `x, y & z` and you can make that available back in the caller the same way you do `a` (your array of employee data), e.g.

```
typedef struct {    /* provide a struct for heading values */
    char x[MAXID],y[MAXID],z[MAXID];
} heading;
```

You are performing *Input Critical* operations in `read_file` yet your return type is `void`? If there is any chance of failure in your function, you need to choose a meaningful return type that can indicate success/failure. While you are at it, why not return the number of employee records read instead of passing the pointer to `i`?

That way you can indicate failure with a `return 0;` and indicate success by returning the positive number of records read -- which can be assigned to `amount` back in the caller eliminating the need to monkey with incrementing the value held by the pointer `i` altogether. (and since it will be a count, a proper type would be `size_t` rather than `int` -- you won't have a negative count)

As mentioned in the comment, you generally want to attempt to open the file in the caller and pass an open `FILE*` pointer to your function as a parameter. That allows you to validate you have an open file before calling your `read_file` function. No need for the function call, if the file doesn't exist. Adding those considerations, you could write your `read_file` function as:

```
/* read heading and employee data from open file fp, returning
 * the number of employee records on success, 0 on failure.
 */
size_t read_file (FILE *fp, heading *h, employee *a)
{
    char buf[MAXC]; /* buffer to read each line */
    size_t i = 0;   /* employee record counter (not including heading) */

    if (fgets (buf, MAXC, fp)) {    /* read heading & validate */
        if (sscanf (buf, "%19s %19s %19s", h->x, h->y, h->z) != 3) {
            fputs ("error: invalid 1st line format.\n", stderr);
            return 0;
        }
    }

    while (i < MAXEM && fgets (buf, MAXC, fp)) {    /* read each line */
        if (sscanf (buf, "%19s %19s %f", 
                    a[i].id, a[i].name, &a[i].sal) != 3) {
            fprintf (stderr, "invalid format line %zu.\n", i);
            return i;
        }
        i++;    /* increment count only on successful parse */
    }

    return i;   /* return number of employee records */
}
```

(**note:** how all line of data are read with `fgets` into `buf` before the individual values are parsed from each line. This ensures you consume an entire line of data with each input call. Note also, how the array bounds of each array are protect by using the *field-width* modifier to each *conversion specifier* used in `sscanf` and by including `i < MAXEM` in your read loop)

Opening your file in `main()`, passing the open file pointer along with a pointer to a heading struct and your array of employee data and assigning the return to `amount` allows you to call your function similar to:

```
    if ((amount = read_file (fp, &h, em))) {        /* validate records read */
```

(you can of course, do `amount = read_file (fp, &h, em);` first and then validate with `if (amount) {` -- it's up to you)

A complete `main()` that takes the filename to read as its argument (or reads from `stdin` by default if no argument is given) could be written as follows:

```
int main (int argc, char **argv) {

    heading h = { .x = "" };                /* declare heading struct */
    employee em[MAXEM] = {{ .id = "" }};    /* declare array of employees */
    size_t amount = 0;                      /* counting types use size_t */
    /* use filename provided as 1st argument (stdin by default) */
    FILE *fp = argc > 1 ? fopen (argv[1], "r") : stdin;

    if (!fp) {  /* validate file open for reading */
        perror ("file open failed");
        return 1;
    }

    if ((amount = read_file (fp, &h, em))) {        /* validate records read */
        printf ("%-8s%-12s%s\n", h.x, h.y, h.z);    /* output heading */
        for (size_t i = 0; i < amount; i++)         /* output employee recs */
            printf ("%-8s%-12s%.1f\n", em[i].id, em[i].name, em[i].sal);
    }
    else    /* otherwise throw error that read failed */
        fputs ("error: no data read from file.\n", stderr);
}
```

(the formatting is handled by the *field-width* modifier again used with `print` to preserve your 8-character and 12-character field width for columns 1 & 2 from your data file.)

Putting it altogether you could do:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define MAXID   20  /* don't use magic numbers in your code!         */
#define MAXEM  100  /* if you need a constant, #define one (or more) */
#define MAXNM  256
#define MAXC  1024

typedef struct {    /* provide a struct for heading values */
    char x[MAXID],y[MAXID],z[MAXID];
} heading;

typedef struct {    /* struct for employee data */
    char id[MAXID];
    char name[MAXNM];
    float sal;
} employee;         /* (note: typedef name goes at end...) */

/* read heading and employee data from open file fp, returning
 * the number of employee records on success, 0 on failure.
 */
size_t read_file (FILE *fp, heading *h, employee *a)
{
    char buf[MAXC]; /* buffer to read each line */
    size_t i = 0;   /* employee record counter (not including heading) */

    if (fgets (buf, MAXC, fp)) {    /* read heading & validate */
        if (sscanf (buf, "%19s %19s %19s", h->x, h->y, h->z) != 3) {
            fputs ("error: invalid 1st line format.\n", stderr);
            return 0;
        }
    }

    while (i < MAXEM && fgets (buf, MAXC, fp)) {    /* read each line */
        if (sscanf (buf, "%19s %19s %f", 
                    a[i].id, a[i].name, &a[i].sal) != 3) {
            fprintf (stderr, "invalid format line %zu.\n", i);
            return i;
        }
        i++;    /* increment count only on successful parse */
    }

    return i;   /* return number of employee records */
}

int main (int argc, char **argv) {

    heading h = { .x = "" };                /* declare heading struct */
    employee em[MAXEM] = {{ .id = "" }};    /* declare array of employees */
    size_t amount = 0;                      /* counting types use size_t */
    /* use filename provided as 1st argument (stdin by default) */
    FILE *fp = argc > 1 ? fopen (argv[1], "r") : stdin;

    if (!fp) {  /* validate file open for reading */
        perror ("file open failed");
        return 1;
    }

    if ((amount = read_file (fp, &h, em))) {        /* validate records read */
        printf ("%-8s%-12s%s\n", h.x, h.y, h.z);    /* output heading */
        for (size_t i = 0; i < amount; i++)         /* output employee recs */
            printf ("%-8s%-12s%.1f\n", em[i].id, em[i].name, em[i].sal);
    }
    else    /* otherwise throw error that read failed */
        fputs ("error: no data read from file.\n", stderr);
}
```

**Compiling**

With gcc:

```
gcc -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -Wshadow -std=c11 -O2 -o idnamesal idnamesal.c
```

With VS Developer's Command Prompt

```
cl /W3 /wd4996 /Ox /Feidnamesal /Tc idnamesal.c
```

**Example Use/Output**

Which when compiled and provided your input file as an argument, would produce the following output:

```
$ ./bin/idnamesal dat/emdata.txt
EmID    EmName      EmsalaryLevel
A001    EgsyPrub    3.4
A002    PattyEin    2.4
A003    TheodoreEly 4.5
```

(output on both Linux and Windows is the same)

Lastly, always compile with *warnings enabled*, and **do not** accept code until it *compiles cleanly without warning*. To enable warnings add `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic` to your `gcc/clang` compile string (also consider adding `-Wshadow` to warn on shadowed variables). For **VS** (`cl.exe` on windows), use `/W3`. Read and understand each warning -- then go fix it. They will identify any potential problems, and the exact line on which it occurs. You can learn a lot by listening to what your compiler is telling you.

There are many ways to put this read together, so don't take this as the only way. The key, regardless how you do it, is the **validate** every critical step in your program and always protect your array bounds from overrun. Doing that alone will save you no end of grief as you learn C.

Answer (score 1):

There are two main issues that cause the code not to work properly:

1. Inside the first loop that reads from the file, you try to increase the value pointed to by i. However, you actually increase the value of i itself and then try to dereference it, which causes invalid memory access. In order to solve it, surround the dereferencing operation with parenthesis, so that it will be executed first:

   ```
   (*i)++;
   ```
2. You forgot to use your new index variable, t, in the second loop for printing the data. Instead you just use the same index value (*i) for all of the iterations. You should also start your count from 0, same as the initial value of *i.

   ```
   for (int t=0;t<*i;t++){
       printf("%s\n%s\n%f\n",a[t].id,a[t].name,a[t].sal);
   }
   ```